# How to do dynamic v-model name binding in Vue

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, vuex, v-model, vuex-map-fields

In Vue2, I am using [vuex-map-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-map-fields) which enables two-way data binding for form fields saved in a Vuex store.

My map fields looks like this-

```
...mapFields("myModule", {
  A_grade: "obj.A_grade",
  B_grade: "obj.B_grade",
}),
```

and I am using it in my template like this-

```
<v-select v-if="someCondition" v-model="A_grade" :items="items"></v-select>
<v-select v-else v-model="B_grade" :items="items"></v-select>
```

This is working perfectly. The only concern is I have to write this `v-select` component twice. So, to make it dynamic I tried something like this-

```
// I want v-model to be resolved as 'A_grade' or 'B_grade'
<v-select v-model="fit + '_grade'" :items="items"></v-select>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fit: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapFields("myModule", {
      A_grade: "obj.A_grade",
      B_grade: "obj.B_grade",
    }),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fit = this.someCondition ? 'A' : 'B'
  }
}
```

But it ends up with a syntax error-

```
Assigning to rvalue
```

Eslint error-

```
v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS
```

Is there any way I can create a `v-model` from the map fields' names?

I set up a **[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-map-fields-basic-example-forked-3005zf?file=/src/App.vue:135-147)** here. Uncomment the last input field and you should see the error.

Comment: Btw, no reason to use a plugin for two-way data binding for form fields saved in a Vuex store. There is a native way https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Comment: @LastM4N, Yeah, I agree. But its an old code, I can't remove this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is not binding the `A_grade` or `B_grade` variable to the v-model, but a string with the value of `A_grade` or `B_grade`. As `fit + '_grade'` will translate to be a plain string, not a reference to one of the variables.

The way you could make this work is by creating an object `grades` with two keys, A and B, in your store (I use the code from your sandbox):

```
state: {
    grades: {
      A: "",
      B: ""
    },
    A_grade: "",
    B_grade: ""
},
```

Now in your `app.vue`, get the value with mapFields. Also add a variable `fit` to your data to make this available in the template.

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  mounted() {},
  data() {
    return {
      fit: "B",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // The `mapFields` function takes an array of
    // field names and generates corresponding
    // computed properties with getter and setter
    // functions for accessing the Vuex store.
    ...mapFields(["A_grade", "B_grade", "grades"]),
  },
};
```

Then in your template you can bind the `grades` object to the input, using `fit` as the key. Something like:

```
<label>{{ fit }}: </label>
<input v-model="grades[fit]" />
<button @click="fit = fit === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A'">Toggle grade</button><br />
Grade A:{{ grades["A"] }} <br />
Grade B: {{ grades["B"] }} <br />
{{ grades }}<br />
```

I just added a button to toggle `fit`, so you can see that it works.

This works, however I do not know if this is a better solution than just using `v-if` and `v-else` in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Gabe. I also think this approach but again I am confused if I should maintain an extra object or not use these two keys A and B. That's why I asked if there is any way to build a dynamic variable for the v-model.